# Why are the network resources empty in Safari timelines, even if resources are there?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

Every single page I go to, the Timelines->NetworkRequests tab shows lots of requests and their timing (top half of the pane), but the bottom half is empty, making it impossible for me to see what requests were made.

I know this is something simple I am overlooking, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out what it is.

Here is an image from loading Wikipedia:

[image: blank inspector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshort, I notice you don't set the time scope, please refer my screenshot, notice the red-mark I made.[image]

Comment: Thank you. Gee, they could have made it clearer in the docs!